# PHP - Applying conditions between certain timeframes

Tags: php

I didn't know what to write for the title, but I'll try to explain my problem.

I have a list of hours worked by an employee at McDonald's. E.g:

> Dec. 1 : 1.55PM - 12AM
>
> Dec. 2 : 6.30AM - 7PM

I also have a list of how an employee gets paid. E.g:

> Mon - Fri: $17/hr
>
> Saturday: $32/hr
>
> 10PM - 4AM: $22/hr

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way of calculating the money this employee gets using the "per hour" rules I have (more may be added later so I can't think statically).

At the moment I'm incrementing 5 minutes from the start time until the end, and checking if those 5 minutes have rules applied but it's slow and messy, and I'm thinking I'm missing something obvious. Would love some suggestions. Thanks :)

Comment: Rather than incrementing per 5 minutes, can you not take the start and end date/time of their shift, and see whether it intersects a specific pay rate, and breakdown their shift by the boundaries found, calculating the time difference in minutes between the start and end of each boundary, multiplying it by the pay rate?

Comment: Show us your code.  Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).